# Access error running chrome from grunt test

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, karma-runner

I am trying to run karma tests on my angular project. I used yeoman to create the angular project. However when I am trying to run tests, I am getting following errors

```
grunt test
Running "clean:server" (clean) task

Running "concurrent:test" (concurrent) task

Running "coffee:dist" (coffee) task

Running "coffee:test" (coffee) task

Done, without errors.

Running "connect:test" (connect) task
Started connect web server on localhost:9000.

Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma server started at http://localhost:8080/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/home/arpit/proj/proj1/views/test/mock/**/*.js" does not  
match any file.
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome
Error: spawn EACCES
INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again.
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome
Error: spawn EACCES

INFO [launcher]: Trying to start Chrome again.
ERROR [launcher]: Cannot start Chrome
Error: spawn EACCES
Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I can run chrome from bash using same account successfully with which I am trying to run grunt test
Also, sudo grunt test is running fine.

Comment: Is this a problem with how you installed a node dependency? You may need to do a `sudo npm -g install ...` something instead of installing the module locally.

Answer (score 3):

On the Mac, it's important to set `CHROME_CANARY_BIN`
to binary file, not just to app package.

In my case, problem emerged from installing Chrome via `brew cask`, so I had to set

`export CHROME_CANARY_BIN="/opt/homebrew-cask/Caskroom/google-chrome-canary/latest/Google Chrome Canary.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Canary"`

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you have to set a environment variable "CHROME_BIN" to point at your chrome.exe

Windows:

```
set CHROME_BIN=C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, but this is how grunt locates the chrome binary. I already have this entry set.

Answer (score 1):

Mac 10.7.5

I was able to set it using the following

export CHROME_BIN=/Applications/Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome

You get to the exec file by right clicking on the .app and selecting the Show Package Contents option.  Follow this down to the executable and click it.  It brought up the path in the terminal.